# Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix()

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

So I'm reading *Android 6 for Programmers: An App-Driven Approach* and the first two app examples I had no issues with the examples, this time the FlagQuiz example when loaded in Android Studio 3.0 Canary-3 I'm getting this error which isn't letting me build the project:

> Error:Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix().
>   The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
>   To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>   Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.

You can download the source from the book site [here](http://www.deitel.com/Books/Android/AndroidforProgrammersAnAppDrivenApproach3/tabid/3671/Default.aspx) to test with the same code base that I'm testing from.

Answer (score 660, accepted):

Alright I figured out how to fix this issue.

- Open build.gradle and change the gradle version to the recommended version:
  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'` to
  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'`
- Hit `'Try Again'`
- In the messages box it'll say `'Fix Gradle Wrapper and re-import project'` Click that, since the minimum gradle version is `3.3`
- A new error will popup and say `The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0` - Hit `Update Build Tools version and sync project`
- A window may popup that says `Android Gradle Plugin Update recommended`, just update from there.

Now the project should be runnable now on any of your android virtual devices.

Comment: I really don't understand why Google makes things harder.

Comment: @AhmetCanAkgül It doesn't !!

Comment: in my case classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2' working.

Comment: It certainly is a bit of a chore.

Comment: @ACAkgul Yep, we are updating our apps less often now, every time we do this is a massive chore, a simple bug fix means we have to update our environment and spend hours (if not days) to switch to new APIs and environment. People make fun of Microsoft, now I think MS are angels!

Comment: I had an old project that I needed to update and ran into this issue.  This solution worked perfectly.

Comment: You don't really need to do any of this it's only to satisfy Android Studio. You can simply do a gradle build from the command line `./gradlew assembleRelease` without changing anything in your config files.

Comment: Open build.gradle and change the gradle version to the recommended version:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' to
**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3**'

Comment: I hope there is a shortcut.

Comment: Solution from srs takes less time.

Comment: Got into same issue and all the above steps shared went well.  But finally at the end, got stuck with below error:  

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Comment: After following above steps, stuck in **ERROR**: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1
**Add Google Maven repository and sync project**
**Show in Project Structure dialog**
**Affected Modules: app**

Comment: What's even the point of gradlew if I'm forced to update...

Comment: ****I really don't understand why Google makes things harder*** this is NOT the problem with google/android only. That is a malady that has happened to the world. The tech-world has become art-less and hence heartless, senseless, modesty-less, android dev, it will download a 1000 files to say hello world and still cry something is NOT found

Answer (score 91):

For Android Studio 3 I need to update two files to fix the error:--

**1. app/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

**2. app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: This worked for me. Should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: @srs, please explain why in dependencies block gradle version 3.0.1, but in gradle-wrapper file 4.1? Shouldn't it be the same version?

Comment: Interesting, but couldn't do this in really old project. Then I just changed gradle version not to 3.0.1 but to 2.2.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 49):

First, open your application module  **build.gradle** file.

Check the **classpath** according to your project dependency. If not change the version of this classpath.

**from:**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

**To:**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
```

or higher version according to your gradle of android studio.

If its still problem, then change **buildToolsVersion**:

**From:**

```
buildToolsVersion '21.0.0'
```

**To:**

```
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

then hit 'Try again' and gradle will automatically sync.
This will solve it.

Answer (score 16):

In my case, Android Studio 3.0.1, I fixed the issue with the following two steps.

Step 1: Change Gradle plugin version in project-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Step 2: Change gradle version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 11):

I also faced the same issue and got a solution very similar:

1. Changing the classpath to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

   [Image after adding the classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRCtN.png)
2. A new message indicating to Update Build Tool version, so just click that message to update.
   [Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DIa2.png)

Comment: Please paste your code directly into the answer as opposed to using images.

Answer (score 10):

Change your gradle version or update it

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

alt+enter and choose "replace with specific version".

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by changing the gradle file.

```
 build.gradle > change
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
    gradle-wrapper.properties > update
    distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

If this ()Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix Android Project is old and you have updated Android Studio, what I did was simply **CLOSE PROJECT** and ran it again. It solved the issue for me. Did not add any dependencies or whatever as described by other answers.

Answer (score -1):

I did the following to make this run on AS 3.5

1. app/ build.gradle

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 21
       buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.android.mobileperf.render"
       minSdkVersion 14
       targetSdkVersion 21
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   ```

   }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}

2. build.gradle

   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           mavenCentral()
           maven {
               url 'https://maven.google.com/'
               name 'Google'
           }
           google()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
       }
   }
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           google()
       }
   }
3. gradle-wrapper.properties

   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip