# Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix() while trying to import my project

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, project

I am facing this error when I'm trying to import my project

```
Error:Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

Here is the code on `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test.creative"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

Any help is appreciated
Thx

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44547225/7295614)?