# I can’t import a project from GitHub on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to import this project app from GitHub, but something is wrong about the versions. *[Android-App-From-Responsive-Website-NavDrawer](https://github.com/TechCybo/Android-App-From-Responsive-Website-NavDrawer)*.

I tried the post *[Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546849/unsupported-method-baseconfig-getapplicationidsuffix)*, but nothing helped.

> Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix().
> The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
> To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
> Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model. (6 s 306 ms)

#### My [build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old project and needs to be updated in order to compile on current Android Studio versions, and in order to be publishable on Play Store.

I was able to compile it by upgrading to Gradle 2.3.3 and and SDK Version 25.

Following is the diff: remove the lines starting with `-` minus sign and add the lines starting with the `+` plus sign. You don't need to add/remove curly braces.

*build.gradle:*

```
-        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
+        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

**After doing the above change**, Build the Project. It's going to fail. Now, click on `Fix Gradle wrapper and reimport project` present on Build Console. Then follow the next diff.

*app/build.gradle:*

```
 android {
-    compileSdkVersion 23
-    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
+    compileSdkVersion 25
+    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.mywebsite.mywebsite"
     minSdkVersion 14
-    targetSdkVersion 23
+    targetSdkVersion 25
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
 }

 dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 -    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
 -    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
 +    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
 +    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
  }
```

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: there is no Fix Gradle wrapper and reimport project

Comment: got it and working, and i can run on my phone BUT, there is a windo the a message Please Wait.. Website is loading.... and keep looping for ever. where is this file and how to fix it

Comment: I'm also facing this same popup message. I clicked outside of it, then it disappeared. At least it was able to load some content, like News report.

Comment: yea probably the time within the phone contact with their servers any ways i added my own sites. BUT the first one when the app is loading says to open the site google chrome's apps from phone i dont want that i want when someone opening the app to open just there ON THE APP not external apps.

Comment: dude? you know how to fix it?

Comment: No, since you're pointing now to your sites, I don't know what is it exactly you're trying to do, and what exactly errors you're getting. By the way, your question should actually be something along the lines: `How to import an old Gradle 1.3 Android project on Android Studio $YourAndroidVersion`. Don't be afraid to post a new question with a detailed description, and in a way the community can reproduce your error.

Comment: I fixed that problem with your solution sir, i made another post if you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583582/the-site-loads-from-external-google-chrome-inside-webvie

Comment: sir?any answer?