# Older files not loading in Android Studio

Tags: android

I made a project back in 2015 and have not used Android Studio since. Today I loaded file and everything was working but I clicked the new version available which loaded 3.3 computer crashed and I had to load AS from AS website. New version 3.3 is the version but now I get errors when loaded project. I have been working through the errors but stuck on gradle. 2.2 is required and current version 4.10. here is the file for gradle and its correct, 
C:/Projects/Android_Studio/SimpleRGB-Working/SimpleRGB/.gradle/gradle-2.2-src/gradle-2.2

Any thoughts  ?

Comment: You're probably going to want to walk through all your dependencies and upgrade them

Comment: Yes I have tried most of the solutions posted.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546849/unsupported-method-baseconfig-getapplicationidsuffix

Comment: Make sure that your gradle-wrapper.properties is referencing the updated version

Answer (score 0):

Decided to cancel the app and will no longer search for solution.