# Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix(). somehting missed in my build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio-4.0

i know the problem is stated at : [Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546849/unsupported-method-baseconfig-getapplicationidsuffix),  but the thing is that i don't have 'classpath' in builde.gradle file at all to change it. here is the build.gradle content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


}
```

android studio 4.0.
i am new to android,
any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your project's build.gradle file add this

```
 dependencies {
  classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: tnx for your help, i added: classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0",  but it is saying: Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0] on project ':objects'.

Comment: you should add your projects build.gradle not app build.gradle

Comment: refer this https://developer.android.com/studio/build

Comment: aha, i did this, now it is giving an error: Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.0-6051327.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.0.0-6051327/aapt2-4.0.0-6051327.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :objects

Comment: and when i open the repository, this is the content: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Could not find resource"
  } ]
}